# How do I keep a user signed-in even after I refresh the page in react?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session

I have a login page that works, however, once i'm logged in and redirected to the next page, if i refresh i'm kicked out and redirected to the login page again. How do i prevent this from happening? How do i stay logged-in even after a refresh?

```
handleSubmit(values, { resetForm, setStatus, setSubmitting, props }) {
    let username = values.username;
    let password = values.password;

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/users/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 404) {
          setStatus({ username: "This username has not been registered." });
        } else if (res.status === 401) {
          setStatus({ password: "Incorrect password." });
        } else {
          res.json();
          auth.login(() => {
            props.history.push("/portal");
          });
        }
      })
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    resetForm();
    setSubmitting(false);
  }
```

Comment: What auth.login() function does?

Comment: How about using a JWT and localStorage? There's a good example here: https://medium.com/@maison.moa/using-jwt-json-web-tokens-to-authorize-users-and-protect-api-routes-3e04a1453c3e

Comment: You need to set a cookie to keep the user logged in. Do it on the server side.

Comment: Do you return a jsonwebtoken from your api when user is logined?

Answer (score -2):

You can use Async Storage for this purpose , it will keep the user signed in when the page is reloaded

you can check here for more details and understanding about how to use AsyncStorage
https://gist.github.com/pradeep1991singh/60f8ee10975307f908f4912cf6996e97

Comment: It's not clear from the question if they are using react native. Please consider asking more details before answering.